# Propel case-insensitive order by usage problem

Tags: sql-order-by, criteria, propel, case-insensitive

I have been looking around for days and couldnt find anything helpfull.

my problem is; I couldn't set criteria case-insensitive ORDER (A a b B D d). Because when I try to fetch my records from DB, its not ordering properly since ascii problems (A B C a b c )

I want to set my ORDER criteria like this;

```
Criterias::setCriterias(Array('ORDER' => 'UPPER(name)'));
```

But propel doesnt let me to use UPPER in setting criterias.
So I have to set it like this;

```
Criterias::setCriterias(Array('ORDER' => 'name'));
```

I found something that may help, this function is doing what i want;

```
setIgnoreCase(true)
```

A new problem is coming with this function. If I set ORDER criteria without WHERE, it will working like a charm. But if I set 'WHERE' and 'ORDER' together, propel will giving me error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PropelException' with message 'Unable
>   to execute SELECT statement []
>   [wrapped: Cannot fetch TableMap for
>   undefined table: ]' in
>   /usr/local/share/pear/propel/query/ModelCriteria.php:1153
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/share/pear/propel/query/ModelCriteria.php(1019):
>   ModelCriteria->getSelectStatement(NULL)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the full Propel querying code you have so far, and tell which version of Propel you are using ?

Comment: Ok after a quick search I found that you have opened a bug: http://www.propelorm.org/ticket/1314 Thanks for Propel team :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Propel 1.6.x. I pushed a few tests to prove that: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/commit/3fc74ccffb05931ec3187b0dcff77dce732ef325

Comment: I havent upgrade to new version yet. But I'm very happy to hear that!